# Fix permisions in a docker image running as non root

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a docker image I am building and it uses the following dockerfile

```
RUN groupadd -r geoserverusers -g 10001 && \
useradd -M -u 10000 -g geoserverusers geoserveruser
RUN chown -R geoserveruser:geoserverusers /usr/local/tomcat ${FOOTPRINTS_DATA_DIR}
```

To run the image I do `docker run —name fix -it kartoza/geoserver:2.16.2 bash`
If I exec into the container the permissions look alright. Inside the container I run `touch test. txt`and the file permission is correct.But if I copy the file using docker cp the file permissions are wrong. If I create an empty file the same way I did in the container and run `docker cp fix.txt fix:/opt/geoserver/data_dir`. Outside the container the files are owner by a normal user called john.How can I correct this so that the file permissions are all correct.
[image]

Comment: Is the image you've attached to this the sample data you're trying to include in the container?  Can you include your `docker run` and `docker cp` commands?

Comment: What are the file permissions and ownership at the source (before the cp). Please include a reproducible example and replace images of text with formatted text. I can't copy and paste from the image to include in an answer.

Comment: I have edited the question to include the instructions you have requested